# Adding a method to Ruby Array open class

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to add an `all_empty?` method to the core Ruby `Array` class as so:

```
class Array
  def all_empty?
    ...
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the following test fail:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Array do
  context "#all_empty?" do
    it "returns true if all elements of the Array are empty" do
      expect(["", "", ""].all_empty?).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `all_empty?' for ["", "", ""]:Array
   Did you mean?  empty?
 # ./spec/core_extensions_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I get the spec to recognize that I've already defined the `all_empty?` method?

**EDIT:** This is the spec_helper.rb file contents that is asked for in the comments below:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
require_relative "../lib/tic_tac_toe.rb"
```

Comment: What is in `spec_helper`? How is the code loaded?

Comment: Make sure your `Array` monkeypatch is loaded _before_ test is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `require` the file into your spec to qccess the method(`all_empty?`) you define for array this. or you can require it in spec_helper.rb

think rspec by default adds your local `lib` directory to the load path as well.

let say it is in `lib/array_method.rb`

```
class Array
  def all_empty?
    ...
  end
end
```

Now in spec you should `require` this

```
require `array_method`

describe Array do
  context "#all_empty?" do
    it "returns true if all elements of the Array are empty" do
      expect(["", "", ""].all_empty?).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

or in `spec_helper.rb`

```
require `array_method`
```

and then

your code for spec

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Array do
  context "#all_empty?" do
    it "returns true if all elements of the Array are empty" do
      expect(["", "", ""].all_empty?).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```